# Discord.net and TwitchLib C# Communication

Tags: c#, twitch, discord.net

I am stuck on a personal project to create a question bot for a twitch channel I mod for. The idea is to take questions in channel with the prefix [q] followed by the question. It then posts the question into #questions in discord. I have both sides of the bot working in their own right, however, I cannot figure out how to actually send a message to discord from that point. Here is an example of what I have.

Twitch receiving a messaging:

> ```
>     TwitchClient tclient;
>     DiscordClient dclient;
>     CommandService commands;
>    private void Client_OnMessageReceived(object sender, OnMessageReceivedArgs e)
>     {
>         if (e.ChatMessage.Message.StartsWith("[q]", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
>         {
>           // Do stuff here  
>
>         }
>         } else if(e.ChatMessage.Message.StartsWith("!uptime", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
>         {
>             tclient.SendMessage(GetUptime()?.ToString() ?? "Offline");
>         } else if(e.ChatMessage.Message.StartsWith("[test]", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
>         {
>             tclient.SendMessage("Received");
>         }
>     }
> ```

And on the discord side I can send a message directly to them via:

> ```
>     public void dMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
>     {
>         //TODO: Add !clearall to clear a channel
>         //TODO: Add !start and !stop
>         if (e.Message.RawText.StartsWith("test"))
>         {
>             e.Channel.SendMessage(e.User.Mention + "Test confirmed");
>         }
>         else if (e.Message.RawText.StartsWith("test2"))
>         {
>             e.User.SendMessage("Test 2 confirmed");
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

Or I can:

> ```
>         commands.CreateCommand("test").Do(async (e) =>
>         {
>             await e.Channel.SendMessage("test 1 confirmed");
>         });
> ```

I am using TwitchLib by swiftyspiffy 1.4.9 nuget.org/packages/TwitchLib/1.4.9 and Discord.Net 0.9.6 w/ Discord.Net.Commands 0.9.6

But the scopes of the two sides seem to be completely independant and I cannot figure out how to get them to communicate. I even put them both into one large file for testing purposes. I seem to not grasp something important. I apologize if this is covered somewhere, I couldn't find anything like my problem.

Comment: Could you provide twitch API you are using? i.e. nuget package name and version.

Comment: It is TwitchLib by swiftyspiffy 1.4.9 https://www.nuget.org/packages/TwitchLib/1.4.9/  and Discord.Net 0.9.6 w/ Discord.Net.Commands 0.9.6